# How to change colour of Bootstrap scroll spy and why won't my logos resize?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to create my portfolio for FCC. I have included a scrollspy to use as a navigation bar and I'm trying to change the way the active link looks, but I can't figure out how to change it with CSS. I am also having an issue with resizing the logos under the my skills section, nothing I try seems to be working. I would appreciate any information that would point me in the right direction.

http://codepen.io/JakeMills/pen/MepyEO?editors=1100

```
.nav .nav-pills .nav-stacked .active {
 background-color:white;
 text-decoration: underlined;
}

.aboutme .skillslogo.img-responsive {
 max-height:150px;
 max-width:100px;

 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change link properties here:

```
.nav-pills>li.active>a, .nav-pills>li.active>a:focus, .nav-pills>li.active>a:hover{
color: #fff;
background-color: #337ab7;
}
```

Change logos under skill here:

```
.skillslogo{

}
```

EDIT:

Note that if you want to have a different style for the normal 'active link' and the hover 'active link', you need to separate `.nav-pills>li.active>a, .nav-pills>li.active>a:focus` and `.nav-pills>li.active>a:hover`

Answer (score 0):

With FireBug I found out that the CSS Selector for the color of the active link is:

```
.nav-pills > li.active > a, .nav-pills > li.active > a:focus, .nav-pills > li.active > a:hover
```

Not sure about the picture.
But you could put:

```
.skillslogo {
  max-width: 100px;
}
```